# Slideshow can't return to first slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, slideshow, slide

In this exemple I have 3 slides. When my last slide has finished to display it doesn't return to the first one.

I can't understand why it doesn't return to the first slide.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function() {
             showSlide(0); // show first slide when DOM loaded
        });   


        function showSlide(x) { // x = the number of slide

           $('.boxslideshow .wrap').hide(); // hide all slides
           $('.boxslideshow .wrap').eq(x).css('display', 'block'); // show a slide


         setTimeout(function(){ 

          var slides = $('.boxslideshow .wrap').length; // total number of slides                       

            if (slides == 0) { // if last slide return to first slide
                 showSlide(0);
            } else {
                 showSlide(x+1); // call function showSlide to display all slides
            }

         }, 2000); // timer             
      }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition for restarting is wrong. It only checks the number of slides, but that value doesn't change.

Compare the number of slides to the variable `x`:

```
if (x == slides - 1) { // if last slide return to first slide
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would it return to the first slide?  You are not deleting the .boxslideshow .wrap elements so that length remains constant.  You need to change the first if statement so that it says

```
if (slides === x) { showSlide(0); }
```